# How to horizontally align excel worksheet in browser using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have page that display/view only excel file using PHPExcel and here's my code:

```
<?php
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = 'files/myFile.xlsx';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
?>
```

and it loads perfectly, my problem is, the worksheet is not horizontally align. And also I add this code:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setHorizontalCentered(true);
```

but it gives me no luck.

here's my final code :

```
<?php
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = 'files/myFile.xlsx';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setHorizontalCentered(true);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('php://output');    

exit;
?>
```

Comment: **but it gives me no luck.** -> What error?

Comment: there is no error. it display in left side of the browser although I already put the `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setHorizontalCentered(true);` property. What's the problem of my code why its always showing in left side?

Comment: You do realise that Page Setup properties only apply when you're ___printing___ the worksheet from within MS Excel. What are you actually expecting to see when you load this spreadsheet in MS Excel?

Comment: @MarkBaker: Thank you for that info Sir! Anyways, how can I horizontally align center my worksheet Sir?  Do you have any alternative for that sir?

Comment: Are you trying to set cell alignment? If so, just look at section 4.6.20 of the developer documentation (`Alignment and wrap text`) for examples of setting cell alignment

Comment: @MarkBaker: no the whole sheet must be align horizontally.

Comment: @MarkBaker here the sample image.. [link](http://postimg.org/image/tjk9kgr3x/)

Comment: I'm still not completely sure what you want: do you simply want to display only 2 columns from a larger worksheet?

Comment: no sir. what im trying to do is just simply horizontally align to center of the browser... the output is correct i just want to show it on center of the browser.. as simple as that but I cant find the exact keyword.

Comment: Then you'll need to create a custom HTML Writer, or extend the existing writer to centre the table.... the HTML Writer doesn't do this for you.... you can probably get away with changing the `body` tag at line 344 of the HTML Writer script to apply styling for centring the whole page

Comment: @MarkBaker: thank you for all your responses sir..  I already figure out the problem, I just manipulate it using css.